# high charts xAxis label cannot be display after reset zoom

Tags: highcharts

I recently upgraded highcharts v2.3.3 to 4.0.3, and find my xAxis cannot display correctly after this.

I have a 3 year monthly chart like this: [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/kaii007/3WxsY/)

After zoom to a detail level, and then reset zoom the xAxis label in the selected area disappear:
[image: Screen Capture After Reset Zoom]

Is there any method to fix the problem? thanks a lot!

I found that the maxStaggerLines caused the problem, but I don't want it separate into 2 lines. How can I solve this?

I also find that if I set `maxStaggerLines: 1` in another chart, some label will disappear. Can I turn the auto stagger line/auto detect label overlap function off?

My chart code:

```
$(function () {
var startYear = '2012';
var dataSet = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 36; i++)
    dataSet.push(15);
var series = [];
series.push({data: dataSet});

var xCategoriesMonth = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];

var xCategoriesYear = [];
for (var i = parseInt(startYear) ; i < (parseInt(startYear) + 3) ; i++)
    for (var x = 0; x < 12 ; x++)
        xCategoriesYear.push(i);

$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
      zoomType: 'x',
      type: 'line',
      height: 380,
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: "category",
        labels: {
            formatter: function () {
                var ex = this.axis.getExtremes();

                if ((ex.max - ex.min) > 12) {
                    if (this.value % 3 == 0) {
                        if (xCategoriesMonth[this.value] == "Jan")
                            return xCategoriesMonth[this.value] + '<br>' + xCategoriesYear[this.value];
                        else
                            return xCategoriesMonth[this.value];
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if (this.value % 3 == 0)
                        return xCategoriesMonth[this.value] + '<br>' + xCategoriesYear[this.value];
                    else
                        return xCategoriesMonth[this.value];
                }
            },
            maxStaggerLines: 1,
        },
        tickPixelInterval: $('#container').width() / 36,
        title: {
            text: 'testing',
            offset: 50
        },
        showLastLabel: false, 
        startOnTick: false,
        endOnTick: true,
        minPadding: 0,
        maxPadding: 0,

    },

    yAxis: {
        lineWidth: 1,
    },

    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            allowPointSelect: true,
            lineWidth: 1,
            connectNulls: true,
        },

    },
    series: series,
});
});
```

Comment: Could you provide an example where `maxStaggerLines: 1` gives you a problem? According to the API you can _"set to 1 to disable overlap detection"_.

Comment: In case when you use the loops which choose some categories (from array), what you expect? How categoreis should be printed?

Comment: I wanna to show different Label in different zoom level, so used array instead of categories

Comment: And I tested it should be the problem raised by new function in v3.0.8, it will not render the label if it detected that would be overlaping

Comment: In case when you use staggerLines, and labels are overlapped then are skipped to avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue. For me solution was to add tickInterval: 1 option.
Look to this ticket 
https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/4399

Comment: Welcome to the site! We ask that answers not simply link to a solution because the link could stop working. Could you edit your answer to go into more detail?